# Break on try/throw/catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch, throw

I'm trying to use try/throw/catch to show an error formatted in a proper way in console.log(). If I use this code:

```
var add = function ( a, b ) {
    try {
        if ( typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number' ) throw {
            name: 'TypeError!\n',
            message: 'You must enter two numbers'
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        console.log( e.name + e.message );
    }
    return a + b;
}
console.log( add( 3, undefined ) );
```

My console show:

```
TypeError!
You must use two numbers as parameters
NaN
```

How can I break the function to get only error in the console log and not also the result, in this case NaN? I try to use break statement after console log inside catch but console says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `break` in a loop, you should use return to return from the function. You can also choose not to catch the exception, and letting it flow back to the caller.

**An example:**

```
var add = function ( a, b ) {
    if ( typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number' ) throw {
        name: 'TypeError!\n',
        message: 'You must enter two numbers'
    }
    return a + b;
}

try {
    console.log( add( 3, undefined ) );
} catch ( e ) {
    console.log( e.name + e.message );
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry! It was obvious why I can't use a break statement. However if I use return inside catch the console return `Type Error! You must use two numbers as parameters undefined`, so print on console log also undefined because return statement return always a value. I want print only the error and nothing else.

Comment: And, how can I choose not to catch the exception? I must always use catch or finally after try. Don't have to I?

Comment: Don't use the try and catch in that function, you can leave the throw in this function, but place the try and catch another function. See example if still confused.